# phpmyadmin fatal error calling undefined function mb_strpos

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin

I just upgraded from Xubuntu 19.10 to 20.04.  This moved me from php 7.3 to php 7.4.3 and phpmyadmin 4.9.5+dsfg1-2.

Everything was working prior to the upgrade.  Now, I can successfully access a test php web page and I can display the PHP_info.php page.  However, when I try to access phpmyadmin, it throws a fatal error recorded in the apache2 error log file.  Here it is, expanded for readability:

```
[Tue Sep 15 20:15:09.030096 2020] [php7:error] [pid 2092141] [client ###.###.###.###:53310]
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error:
Call to undefined function PhpMyAdmin\\mb_strpos() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php:253
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php(206): PhpMyAdmin\\Url::getArgSeparator()
#1 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php(169): PhpMyAdmin\\Url::getCommonRaw()
#2 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(749): PhpMyAdmin\\Url::getCommon()
#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(330): PhpMyAdmin\\Core::linkURL()
#4 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(353): PhpMyAdmin\\Core::getPHPDocLink()
#5 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(973): PhpMyAdmin\\Core::warnMissingExtension()
#6 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(106): PhpMyAdmin\\Core::checkExtensions()
#7 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(27): require_once('/usr/share/phpm...')
#8 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php on line 253, referer: http://<server>/html/admin.html
```

How is it that the function **mb_strpos()** is not defined?

Any suggestions on how to address this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mb_strpos` is not a default function in core PHP, it's contained in the `mbstring` extension.  You can easily install it with `sudo apt install php-mbstring`

Comment: Thanks, that did it once I restarted apache2.  It's interesting that this package was automatically installed and updated in the past for php 7.0 and 7.2, but not for 7.4.  I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: I was thinking about that part and the only idea I came up with was maybe you installed it previously by specifying the `php7.2-mbstring` package rather than the `php-mbstring` virtual package.  If so, it's possible Ubuntu didn't recognize `php7.2-mbstring` -> `php7.4-mbstring` was an upgrade path (they're separate packages, not just a different version) but hopefully you're set now by using the virtual package.

Comment: I already have php-mbstring and still get the error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out which PHP your server is using by placing a **info.php** with this code:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then you need to download php-mbstring for this version, e.g. if you have PHP 8.0.15 then you need to install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-mbstring
```

Then restart the apache2 service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because I was using php7.0-mbstring. Fixed it by installing php7.2-mbstring.